# Comment traduire l'emploi adjectival « laisser-faire » dans « laisser-faire approach » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, adjectifs

> [...] Roth warned Musk’s *laissez-faire* approach to content moderation,
> and his lack of a transparent process for making and enforcing
> platform policies, has made Twitter less safe [...] 
> [ [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2022/11/29/tech/yoel-roth-twitter-elon-musk/index.html), en italiques dans l'article ]

Il s'agit de l'emploi au figuré de l'adjectif [*laisser-faire*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/laissez%E2%80%93faire) (du français « [laisser-faire](https://www.etymonline.com/word/laissez-faire#etymonline_v_2006) » il va sans dire) devant le nom [*approach*](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/approach) (*to content moderation*) découlant de l'idée de « favoring a policy that allows businesses to operate with very little interference from the government » [...avec très peu d'interférence du gouvernement] dans un contexte de *content moderation*.

- Comment traduit-on le « *laisser-faire* approach » en contexte ?

Answer (score 3):

Suivant l'opinion qu'on a d'elle, on pourra parler d'**approche tolérante**, **permissive** ou **laxiste** de la modération.